Accessing Hashicorp Vault secrets within namespaces from Spring boot 3.2.X
I am trying to access Hashicorp Vault secrets from Spring boot application and getting 403 forbidden error. : org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 403 Forbidden [secret/secret]: permission denied
Not sure why it is picking up secret/secret
Our organization uses namespaces in Vault, so I am using spring.cloud.vault.namespace property in application.yml, below is the application.yml :
  spring.cloud.vault.uri=https://vault-qa-aws.xxxx.com 
  spring.cloud.vault.token=secret token
  spring.cloud.vault.generic.backend=kv_1
  spring.cloud.vault.kv.default-context=secret
  spring.cloud.vault.namespace=xxxxxxxx
  #spring.cloud.vault.kv.application-name=${path}
  logging.level.root=DEBUG
  spring.config.import:  vault://

I am using Spring boot 3.2.2 and spring-cloud.config version = 2023.0.2
EDIT
In the path section I see the API path is given like this :
Use this path when referring to this secret in the API. : /v1/US/AWS/APXXXXXX/kv_1/data/secret
I am trying the below command from CLI :
vault kv-get -namespace=US/AWS/APxxxxxxxxx_Q -mount="kv_1" "secret"
It returns an error like below :
Error reading secret: secret.
URL: /v1/secret/data/undefined
Code: 403

Errors:
1 error occurred:
* permission denied

Are you sure you are using a v1 secret backend? +Do a vault login <secret token> and access the same secret using the command line, with both vault kv get ... and vault read ... and add that information to your question.

I was not able to run the kv-get command, everytime it was giving 403 error, however When I checked the API path to access the secret it says :  Use this path when referring to this secret in the API. : /v1/US/AWS/APXXXXXX/kv_1/data/secret.

/v1/US/AWS/APXXXXXX/kv_1/data/secret VS  /v1/secret/data/undefined. Seems like whatever mapping exists between the first and second url, something is badly configured because in the second url the word 'undefined' suddenly pops up which reads to me like some kind of default fallback value if nothing is provided for it.

Thanks, but the idea here is to make sure your Vault configuration is correct. Then we'll deal with Spring. The v1 is part of the API contract and it will be added by Spring, for example. Add the full command line that allows you to get the secret, using the app's token. If it only works with the root token, then we will look at the policies.
